# (help still needed) How to make a playvideo function that returns when video is over?

Tags: java, javafx, runnable

So I am using JavaFX and want to set up an experiment where I have to play many videos and interact with the user. For this setup I would like to write a function that receives a filename and plays the video with that name. But it should only return when the video is over, and not before. So something like this:

```
private void play(URI name){
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(new Media(name));
    mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    view.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
}
```

However this function returns before the video is over, making the execution of the program a complete mess. I know MediaPlayer has a setOnEndOfMedia(Runnable) function but I am not sure how I could potentially use that to achieve my goal.

This is the code I have at the moment. But it does not work. The problem being that both videos are played at the same time, likely because the play function returns as soon as it has started the video. I have also tried just adding a while(true) loop at the end of the play function so that it gets stuck there until the return; in .setOnEndOfMedia is callled, that prevented any video's from being played at all.

CODE:

```
static MediaView view;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
    // Create full screen scene
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    stage.setFullScreen(true);
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), dim.getWidth(), dim.getHeight());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    // Create the view and add it to the Scene.
    view = new MediaView();
    ((Group)scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(view);

    play("videol");
    play("video2");
}

private static void play(String name) throws InterruptedException {
    Media media = new Media(uri(name));
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    player.setOnReady(() -> {
        player.play();
        player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
            player.dispose();
            return;
        });
    });
    view.setMediaPlayer(player);
}

private static String uri(String name) {
    return Paths.get("clips/" + name + ".mp4").toUri().toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping my original stuff since it is useful for others.

Anyways the problem with your code is that you are calling the method twice, right after itself. You need to call the method from within the EndOfMedia part. If you wish you can create a list and for the parameter when using recursion you can use list.poll() to take and remove the first string in the list. Then when the list is null you can just return to the interface. Just some ideas.

What I would suggest you use is to create a method for playing your music which takes a `String` as a parameter, this string would be then used to find its equivalent in a hashmap, say `HashMap<String, MediaPlayer>`. Then to the part where you actually need help. I suggest you write something like this:

```
    mediaPlayer.setOnReady(() -> {
        mediaPlayer.play();
        mediaPlayer.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
            mediaPlayer.dispose();
            MusicPlayer();
        });
    });
```

Basically, you are playing the media when ready and then at the end disposing of it and calling the method again and in where my code uses recursion and calls the method MusicPlayer you can instead 'return'. Sorry if this is poorly explained, if you need further help just comment below.

Comment: I tried your code where I replaced MusicPlayer() by return;. However, when I try to play a few video's after each other, (e.g. play("video_a"); play("video_b"); play("video_c");) It only plays the first video and then stays frozen. It has executed all the code however, I checked this using prints.

Comment: CORRECTION: It plays all video's at the same time (so not only the first one). So how do I stop the first function call from returning before the video is over?

Comment: Are you sure you are using a media type supported by Javafx, also can you provide more code so I can better help you?

Comment: All videos I play are mp4's. I have added the code in the OP.